# JSON parseerror return from AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm doing an AJAX call like so:

```
function getEvents(info){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'get_all_events.php',
    data: {year: info['year'],month: info['month']},          
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(result));
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(XMLHttpRequest.statusText);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
}
```

Which works on the initialization of the calendar app I'm developing. I create an object 'info' and assign it month/date etc... then when the user presses 'Previous' or 'Next' it reassigns certain variables of the 'info' object and calls `getEvents` again. I tried re-writing my query, rewriting my AJAX call, adding contentType... nothing seems to work.

Comment: Did you check, while re-assigning the values in info object, what values do it contain, and what is the value of result? Check these values using console.

Comment: Yes, right before I send them out to the AJAX call, I verified that the JavaScript object 'info' contains the right values (which it does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see if there are any errors in the console. Also make sure, your `get_all_events.php` returns the `valid JSON` string. When you specify `dataType:'json'` jQuery will automatically parse the returned data. If the data that is returned is not a `valid JSON` this error is thrown.

How to check?

Do one thing. Remove `dataType:'json',` attribute from your `$.ajax()` call...
`console.log(result)` in your `success` handler...
Copy the response text from console and paste it inside some online JSON validator (jsonlint.com) if there is and error, update `get_all_events.php` on server side to `echo` the `valid JSON`

Comment: Fantastic idea, I will try this tonight. If this isn't the case, I will setup my debug mode and release the link in an update of my question. Thank you for your suggestion.